# Deciphering between a JSON array and a JSON string in Hive

Tags: arrays, json, hive, udf

I'm trying to process an arbitrary JSON blob which may contains either scalar or array elements. The issue is there are times where I cannot decipher whether the underlying JSON object is a string on an array, i.e. given the following JSON

```
{"array": [0], "string": "[0]"}
```

the following calls to `GET_JSON_OBJECT` both return `TRUE`,

```
GET_JSON_OBJECT('{"array": [0], "string": "[0]"}', '$.array') = '[0]'
```

and

```
GET_JSON_OBJECT('{"array": [0], "string": "[0]"}', '$.string') = '[0]'
```

Is there any good way of deciphering whether the JSON object is an array or scalar? Note in reality the arrays normally contain strings, i.e.,

```
{"array": ["cat"], "string": "[cat]"}
```

and so my possible workaround is to perform a regex match on the output of the form `^\\[".*?"\\]]^` to decipher between an array of strings and a string enclosed in square brackets, though this approach can also be promblematic.